# LL(1) Parsing Table Error

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, computer-science

I start with having this grammar

```
E -> E + T | T
T -> id | id[] | id[X]
X -> E, E | E
```

It's obvious that there's left recursion in the first rule, so I remove it to get the following

```
E  -> TE'
E' -> +TE' | epsilon
T  -> id | id[] | id[X]
X  -> E, E | E
```

From here I produce the `FIRST` and `FOLLOW` sets (`id` is a single terminal).

```
FIRST(TE') = FIRST(E, E) = FIRST(E) = {id}
FIRST(+TE') = {+}
FIRST(epsilon = {epsilon}
FIRST(id) = FIRST(id[]) = FIRST(id[X]) = {id}

FOLLOW(E) = {$}
FOLLOW(E') = {$}
FOLLOW(T) = {$}
FOLLOW(X) = {]}
```

But when I try to construct the parse table, I end up with multiple values for a couple of cells.

```
    |  id               |  +     | [  |  ]  |  ,  |  $  |
----+-------------------+--------+----------+-----+-----+
E   |  TE'              |        |    |     |     |     |
E'  |                   |  +TE'  |    |     |     |  ε  |
T   |id or id[] or id[X]|        |    |     |     |     |
X   |E, E or E          |        |    |     |     |     |
```

Am I missing something? How do rectify this so that I can parse `id + id[id + id, id[]]` using this grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar, even after removing left recursion, is not LL(1). These productions are problematic:

```
T -> id | id[] | id[X]
X -> E , E | E
```

Try to apply the following transformation:

```
A -> ab_1 | ... | ab_n  ~~~~~~> A  -> aA'
                                A' -> b_1 | ... | b_n
```

In your case it is:

```
T  -> id T'
T' -> [] | [X] | epsilon

X  -> EX'
X' -> , E | epsilon
```

But `T'` still needs to apply the transformation one more time:

```
T  -> id T'
T' -> [ T" | epsilon
T" -> ] | X ]
```

Full grammar:

```
E  -> TE'
E' -> +TE' | epsilon
T  -> id T'
T' -> [ T" | epsilon
T" -> ] | X ]
X  -> EX'
X' -> , E | epsilon
```

Moreover, you should do the steps in the following way:

1) Compute FIRST for all nonterminals.

2) Compute FOLLOW for all nonterminals.

3) Compute SELECT for all productions. Keep in mind that SELECT sets for one nonterminal should be disjoint.

Comment: Grzes, one question though, is the epsilon here `T" -> ] | X ] | epsilon` correct? This would allow productions with only the left hand side of the bracket `[`.

Comment: @Grzes, if you have the time, could you elaborate briefly on what exactly makes the two productions you mention problematic?  I was trying to answer this question yesterday for practice and I was apparently going completely in the wrong direction.  Guess I am rusty on the material...

Comment: LL(1) parser looks at the stack and at the first remaining input lexeme to determine which production to choose. When at the top of the stack is a non-terminal `T` and the next input lexeme is `a`, the automata proceeds as follows: 1) choses production `T -> x` where `a in SELECT(T -> x)` 2) `T` is replaced with `x` on the stack (note that `x` is a chain of symbols, both terminals and non-terminals).
To sum up, when `T` is on the top of stack, and SELECT sets of productions of non-terminal `T` are not disjoint, there is a conflict. Parser does not know which production to select.

Comment: `SELECT(T -> id) = {id}, SELECT(T -> id [ ]) = {id}, SELECT(T -> id[ X ]) = {id}`. You can see that based on the first input lexeme your are not able to choose production. LL(2) should cope with this case easily, but there is no need for LL(2), you can just apply aforementioned transformations.